# Cannot send list to Recycler View adapter Android

Tags: android

I have an `ArrayList` and the list gets data from retrofit and its working good. The problem is when I try to send the list to `RecyclerView` adapter, its empty! Any idea ?

This is **Activity**

```
public class ToDoRecycler extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView todoRecyclerView;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter todoAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager todoLayoutManager;
    public List<ToDo>results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_recycler);


        todoRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.todoRecyclerView);
        todoRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        results= new ArrayList<ToDo>();
        todoLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        todoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(todoLayoutManager);
        todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
        todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
        getRetrofitObject();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ToDoRecycler.this,AddToDo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});}

   public void getRetrofitObject() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<Result> call = service.getresults();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                results = response.body().getResults();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            }});}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class TodoRecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
static List<ToDo> todoResults;
static Context context;
List<ToDo>results;
public TodoRecyclerAdapter(List<ToDo> results) {
    this.todoResults = results;
}
@Override
public TodoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_items, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final TodoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  todoResults.size();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView todoTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        todoTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.todo_title);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating/calling adapter before the the results coming from retrofit...!

You should wait for the results and when you get the result, initialize and set the adapter to the recyclerview in the callback...!

Use the below code to get some help,

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                    results = response.body().getResults();
 todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results));               
}
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());

                }});}
```

and remove the adapter initialization from onCreate() method

**Update:**
Your activity class should be look like the below one,

```
public class ToDoRecycler extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView todoRecyclerView;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter todoAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager todoLayoutManager;
    public List<ToDo>results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_recycler);


        todoRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.todoRecyclerView);
        todoRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        results= new ArrayList<ToDo>();
        todoLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        todoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(todoLayoutManager);
        getRetrofitObject();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ToDoRecycler.this,AddToDo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});}
}

   public void getRetrofitObject() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<Result> call = service.getresults();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                results = response.body().getResults();
                todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TodoRecyclerAdapter(ActivityName.this,results));    
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            }});}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two lines

```
todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
```

to this:

```
todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

Comment: this is not my problem

Answer (score 0):

Construct the adapter first and then add the adapter to your `RecyclerView`

```
todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

Then you need to notify the adapter about the change in the dataset you're referring to like this

```
public void getRetrofitObject() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<Result> call = service.getresults();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            results = response.body().getResults();
            // Call notifyDataSetChanged here 
            todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }});}
```

**Update**

So while setting the `results` for the first time, obviously its `null` as there's no data in it. You need to handle this in your `TodoRecyclerAdapter`. Simply you can check the `null` value in the `getCount` function and return 0 like this

```
public int getCount() {
    if(results != null) return results.size();
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you i use this , but the 

 todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
results is null !

Comment: You need to check for null values in the adapter. You can post your adapter code, so that I can check that too.

Comment: ok i will post my adapter but when i but break point  here , 
        todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
this results is null

Comment: Please post your adapter and then notify me by commenting here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your onBindViewHolder method is missing an implementation and your ViewHolder constructor does not return a ViewHolder..